# Quisiera saber como accedo a los datos de la respuesta de la apigraph de facebook

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4, facebook-api

estoy intentando acceder a la respuesta que trae esta consulta y no he podido estoy usando php  `$response = $this->facebook->get('/id-publicacion/accounts?fields=name,access_token', 'token user');`
imprimo los datos con var dump y me imprimi pero no se como tomar todos los token de todos los datos que me trae